# Localize a WP7 application using MVVM Light

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, mvvm-light, resource-files

I'm using MVVM Light in my Windows Phone 7 application. The application is to be used in English and Spanish. Users can select a different language during runtime. I'm localizing the application using resource files. I've already been able to make the localization works, but only when I change the language from Settings. In the main page, I have a list for users to select the language during runtime, I'm setting the selected language to **Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture**, but the text strings in the interface don't get updated. I have a set of properties in the ViewModel that I'm binding to the View to set the labels of the control, but something is missing. I've been reading that I need to implement the **INotifyPropertyChanged** in the ViewModel to make this works, but I don't know how to exactly do that nor if there is a different better way to implement this case using MVVM Light. Could anybody help me here please?

Comment: Don't let users change the language inside your application. It's better done in the OS itself.

Comment: Thanks Claus. I read the same recommendation while I was researching on how to accomplish what I need. However, for this application, allowing users to change the language in runtime is a requirement that I have to fulfill.

Answer (score 1):

Hum, I wrote a blog post about it sometimes ago ( http://wp7wonders.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/localize-a-windows-phone-7-application/ - read the comments too!). The main point is that you have an object between the resource files and your viewmodels which allow to change the dynamically the language.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu. Your post is helpful. However, it doesn't use MVVM which is how I'm trying to implement my solution. I'm still looking for information on how to implement the dynamic language change (changing language in runtime), but using specifically the "MVVM Light"

Comment: Hum I'm using it with MVVM through databinding and notification between the model and the view.